# Commands with NSTask

Tags: objective-c, macos

So im trying to run some basic terminal commands in my mac app and for some reason(s) I just can't to it.

Heres my code:

```
NSString *commitText = [commitMessage stringValue];
NSString *a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cd %@", dirPath];
NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"usr/bin/git commit -m '%@'", commitText];

NSTask *aTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *args = [NSMutableArray array];
[args addObject:@"-c"];
[args addObject:a];
[args addObject:@"git add *"];
[args addObject:c];
[args addObject:@"git push origin HEAD"];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[aTask setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];


[aTask setLaunchPath:@"bin/sh"];
[aTask setArguments:args];
[aTask launch];
```

Here are the errors:

```
2012-06-09 15:18:50.293 Auto Git[9404:403] launch path not accessible
2012-06-09 15:18:50.297 Auto Git[9404:403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870b4f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90e35d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870b4d8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870b4d14 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff9174f1f4 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 470
    5   Auto Git                            0x0000000109e1365d -[Push push:] + 765
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870a470d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f8f7e -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f8eb2 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 88
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f8ddd -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 137
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f82a0 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2014
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e177fc4 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 489
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f6eaa -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0c2348 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e05ba55 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8dff20c6 -[NSApplication run] + 555
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e26e244 NSApplicationMain + 867
    17  Auto Git                            0x0000000109e12eb2 main + 34
    18  Auto Git                            0x0000000109e12e84 start + 52
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks guys.

Comment: Should `@"usr/bin/git commit -m '%@'"` be `@"/usr/bin/git commit -m '%@'"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launch path should be `/usr/bin/git` and your array should be `@[@"commit",@"-m",yourarg]` You need to create a different task for each command. Your add, push need to be seperate tasks. To find the path of git, in the terminal run the command `which git` This will be the path for your tasks.

```
NSTask* task = [[Task alloc] init]
//set the input output pipes
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/git"];
NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"commit",@"-m",commitMessage];
[task setArguments:args];
//set up the notifications
[task launch];
```

If you want to use a shell script i think you would need to give it more formatting such as:

```
NSString* shScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#!bin/sh\ngit commit -m %@\ngit add ...\ngit..."
```

set it up the same as above with the only argument in the array that string and the launch path /bin/sh

Comment: Ok so could you take my code and give me and example for lets say the commit? I still don't quite get it

Comment: Ok and how do I use which git?

Comment: which git is only for finding the launch path. You don't really need it in the program.