# NSTask launch path not accessible. Works in Xcode. Error shown out of XCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

Ok. There are several questions on stack overflow about this. [This question was the only question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254680/nstask-only-returning-standarderror-in-release-build) comes closest to mines, but it uses notifications.

The code is very simple. Create a new empty Mac OSX project and just paste the following code in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method. It supposed to get the path of any executable file (in this case GIT).

```
NSTask *aTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSPipe *outputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSPipe *errorPipe = [NSPipe pipe];

[aTask setStandardOutput: outputPipe];
[aTask setStandardError: errorPipe];
[aTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"which"]];
[aTask setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/git"];

NSFileHandle *outputFileHandler = [outputPipe fileHandleForReading];
NSFileHandle *errorFileHandler = [errorPipe fileHandleForReading];

[aTask launch];
[aTask waitUntilExit];

// Task launched now just read and print the data
NSData *data = [outputFileHandler readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *outPutValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *errorData = [errorFileHandler readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *errorValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:errorData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Error value: %@",errorValue);
NSLog(@"Output Value: %@",outPutValue);
```

This code sets up two reading pipes and runs one command: `which git`.

If i run this in XCode i get this results corretly:

```
Error value: ""  
Output Value: /usr/bin/git
```

If i go to my build/Products/Debug folder and double click the executable file, i get this message printed on the console app:

[image]

**Question:** So, what is really the problem here? please just dont make an alternative solution... I also want to know what the problem is.. thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK turns out the answer is on stack overflow, but its spread across different questions.

The question was asked here -> [Commands with NSTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965007/commands-with-nstask) and here -> [NSTask launch path not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221432/nstask-launch-path-not-accessible) as well

But their answers as of this date arent clear as to what the problem was. It's only after reading the question from [NSTask not picking up $PATH from the user's environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386783/nstask-not-picking-up-path-from-the-users-environment) (the question's title was misleading) and with these two answers [NSTask not picking up $PATH from the user's environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386783/nstask-not-picking-up-path-from-the-users-environment/1817870#1817870) and [Find out location of an executable file in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208897/find-out-location-of-an-executable-file-in-cocoa/387809#387809) that I realized the solution.

> It looks like this is about setting up either NS
>   Task or the user's shell (e.g., ~/.bashrc) so that the correct
>   environment ($PATH) is seen by NSTask.

Solution:

```
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-l",
                 @"-c",
                 @"which git", //Assuming git is the launch path you want to run
                 nil];
[task setArguments: args];
```

However this assumes the user's shell is **always** bash and it will fail for others. Solve this by determining the shell.

```
NSDictionary *environmentDict = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
NSString *shellString = [environmentDict objectForKey:@"SHELL"];
```